# Ways to batch update DynamoDB table

Tags: database, amazon-dynamodb

I'm planning to create an ETL job that puts data from Redshift to DynamoDB, this data runs daily that aims to update the values stored in DynamoDB. Since there is no way to do batch update of values, I'm doing a **delete** and **create** process on the table where I re-create the table daily with new values.

Issue comes in since there is an API that extracts data from the daily refreshed DynamoDB so I have to ensure that the table in DynamoDB will exist at all times. There is a possibility that the API will be called in a time where the deletion process has happened and re-creation is on-going.

Is there a better way in doing batch "update" in DynamoDB in this case?

DynamoDB Table schema:

- ID: partition-key
- version: sort-key
- score
- timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you make a new table (with a new name) then when it’s ready for traffic delete the old table. You can have a ParameterStore entry that gives the latest table name to the caller.

(If you’re rock climbing, don’t detach a climbing rope until your new one is attached.)